# the best approach for processing submitted time consuming tasks through REST api in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, message-queue, messagebroker, decoupling

I have a spring boot web project which needs to work with a web crawler system. My crawler service works without any downtime and each crawl request maybe have very long time processing. I want to get the URLs for crawl through a REST interface. The user in my web application submits the list of URLs to the web application and I want to show to him/her: your request has been submitted. After the completion of crawl for this request, I want to update the request status in web form. What is the best approach for implementing this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

What if after your URLs has been submitting you return back to the client a token, so from the client side there can be calls to the REST interface on a time basis (like every minute) using the token to ask for the status of the crawl?